# Issue : 2 jQuery plugins on same page (iButton + zclip) on Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, jquery-plugins, zclip

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function(){
       $('#post_status').iButton({
                duration: 200         
                , easing: "swing"                      
                , labelOn: "Active"                                               
                , labelOff: "Hidden"                         
                , resizeHandle: "auto"                    
                , resizeContainer: "auto"                 
       });
    });
$('a.copy').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.zclip({
            path : 'path/to/ZeroClipboard.swf',
            copy : function(){
                    var copyText = $(this).prev().val();
                    return copyText;
                }
        });
    });
});
```

zClip attach flash objects to elements correctly, but when I click, texts are not copied to clipboard.

If I comment iButton's section, zClip will work fine.

Anyone experienced this issue?

P.S. Works fine on Firefox, but not Chrome

P.S.2 Sorry, for my bad English.

Sample Code : http://jsfiddle.net/nHSbc/

Comment: Could you please upload a sample somewhere to see what exactly is happening there? Cheers

Comment: I'm sorry. I can't do that because I work on localhost. I try to use JSbin, but there's no remote file for iButton plugin.

Comment: When you call "copy" does it call the function inside it? Have you had a beak point in it on copying?

Comment: Yes, I use "console.debug", the function is called. The "copyText" contain a value, but that value is not returned.

Comment: You should follow the calling stack and go after copy and see what's happening there. I think the problem is not in the code you mentioned.

Comment: Here is sample code : http://jsfiddle.net/nHSbc/

Comment: Another thing I've found is the behavior of the plugin named "zcip" is different in IE and Chrome. I'm on it.

Answer (score 0):

Please find out why if you comment the if line, everything works fine. just in chrome and firefox it has a problem, not in IE. It seems copy function is empty when you click a button.

It might be a miss-configuration problem in using zclip plugin.

Line 63 - 67, File : jquery.zclip.js

```
//if(!$.isFunction(settings.copy)){
    clip.setText(settings.copy);
//} else {
//  clip.setText(o.triggerHandler('zClip_copy'));
//}
```

Cheers

Comment: I have commented those lines, but the result is the same.

Comment: put a break point on the "if" line and hit one of the buttons and see what is happening. As I checked on my firefox, it doesn't work and I could debug it. I just found out "settings.copy" is not set when you hit a button and it goes to "else" section and triggers "zClip_copy" handler.

Comment: I try on Chrome, but there's no difference. The text is not copied.

Comment: I can't see any message box in chrome and firefox but in IE. Do you have this problem?

Comment: Take a look at the original site of ZClip plugin. The demo works fine every where. http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/

Comment: Without iButton script, it works fine every browsers.

On Firefox, it alerts output text correctly.
On Chrome, there's nothing happens.